# Navigation bar object in xcode 5 not showing back button and has no functionality

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, xcode5

I have been trying to properly setup a navigation bar in one of my View Controllers for an hour now and have not found any working solutions.

I control-clicked on a button on my app's initial view controller(1st VC) and dragged to another view controller(2nd VC) and selected "modal" as the action segue.

I then added a navigation bar item to my 2nd view controller.

When I run my app on my iPhone, I can tap on the button on my app's initial screen and it will take me to my 2nd VC, and the 2nd VC does display the navigation bar, but the navigation bar does not have the default iOS 7 back arrow to let me go back to the app's initial VC.

I was under the impression that this could be setup exactly like I did above and that the back button functionality would be included by default.

Am I completely lost? Do I need to further customize navigation bar programmatically or with a tick box in the attributes inspector? Is "modal" the wrong action segue option?

I basically just want to have navigation bars at the top of a couple of my VC's so that the user can easily get back to the app's initial screen.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are presenting your second screen (2nd VC) as MODAL from your first screen (1st VC), you will not see the back arrow button on navigation bar. Your understanding about back button works for Navigation view controllers (push segue). For MODAL you need to put a cancel button on second VC's Nav bar and put a dismiss action for that.

Comment: For the cancel button, would I drag and drop a button object onto the navigation bar or would I drag and drop a navigation item object?

Comment: Please put UIBarButtonItem and set the properties for title or image. You can then link its action with the IBAction of VC managing it.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly after connecting it with an action and  calling the dismissViewControllerAnimated method!